# How can I achieve these gradient effects in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, interface-design, gradient

I would like to achieve the three gradient effects we see on the photo below with photoshop. I tried by myself using the gradient tool and changing the layer blend mode but didn't work.

The 1st gradient is Pink to Orange to Black but we can see the photo underneath
at the pink and orange area.

The 2nd gradient is pink to Orange, the photo underneath is visible at the pink zone.

The 3rd one transparent to black, I think, im not sure.

The original link : https://dribbble.com/shots/4186500-Music-Player

[image]

Comment: I would say that Illustrator is a better option for this kind of thing.

Comment: Do you know how to do it with Illustrator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a gradient.

You can see where to play with the opacity and color.

See the image below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would say that Illustrator is the much better option to go about doing something like this

When making the gradient (in Illustrator) I set up the gradient as such:

[image]

However, the pink one I clicked and changed the opacity to 90%

Which produces this effect:

[image]

For the black one, I just made one side black and one dark gray:

[image]

and adjusted the opacity on the gray to 50%

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in the gradient pop up, where you select the colour in the small block along the colour scale. on the bottom I believe is the colour and the block on top of the scale has the opacity option in it.